# Update function doesn't work in file in Phaser

Tags: jquery, node.js, browserify, phaser-framework

I have a game with structure like this (some lines of code were deleted, but all files are required by Browserify):

Game needs boot.js and play.js

game.js:

```
w = window.innerWidth * window.devicePixelRatio,
h = window.innerHeight * window.devicePixelRatio;

window.game = new Phaser.Game((h > w) ? h : w, (h > w) ? w : h, Phaser.CANVAS, 'Phaser', {render:render});
game.state.add('Boot', require('./states/boot.js'));
game.state.add('Play', require('./states/play.js'));
```

---

boot.js starts play.js

In boot.js:

```
module.exports = {  

    preload: function() {
      //...
    },

    create: function() {
      game.physics.startSystem(Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);
      game.world.setBounds(0, 0, 6000, 6000);
      this.game.state.start("Play");
    }
  };
```

---

play.js requires interfacePanels.js

In play.js:

```
chat = require('./../chat.js');
interfacePanels = require('./../interfacePanels.js');

module.exports = {

    create: function() {
       interfacePanels.init();
    },

    update: function() {
      //....
    }
};
```

---

There is a method that shows the profile of a player in interfacePanels.js (this file requires profile.js)

Here is the code:

```
     profile = require('./profile.js');
     module.exports = {
        show: function(buttonType) {

           switch(buttonType.key) {
              case 'menuButtonPress':

              break;

              case 'profileButtonPress':
                if(profile.initialized == false) {
                   profile.create();
                   profile.initialized = true;
                }
              break;
           }
        }
     }
```

---

The problem is in profile.js:

```
module.exports = {

   initialized: false,
   START_X: '',
   START_Y: '',

   create: function() {
      //... some code
   },

   update: function() {
      console.log('profile')
   },
};
```

The update function doesn't work at all.

I could try adding the update function to play.js file, but won't there will be a lot if console.log commands if I do?

I need this to move elements to starting points and check whether they overlap or not.

Comment: Do *any* of the functions work? Do assets get loaded? Does `create` get called?

Comment: @PhotonStorm, sure. All functions work well. "Create" gets called.
But "Update" doesn't get called at all.

Comment: @PhotonStorm, Browserify and Phaser work together here

Comment: The few things you shared seem ok, you probably cut down too much of your code for us to help. For instance we can't see how the "profile" module is imported/used at all

Comment: If the other functions are being called then it's something we can't see in the code. My guess is that update is being overwritten by another function from somewhere, hence why you don't see the log.

Comment: @PhotonStorm very interesting, I tried to log all update methods of all files and I got only play.js... and I wonder how that happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was very funny. Thanks @drhayes

```
// In play.js...
var profile = require('./profile');

module.exports = {
   // other state functions...

   update: function() {
       profile.update();
   }
};
```